In GlassFish3, How can I "override" internal library, or give preference to app library?
In GlassFish3, my web application 'sfeaapp' uses a library 'jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final.jar' located in '/var/opt/GlassFish3/domains/sfeaapp/lib/ext/jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final.jar', which conflicts with another internal library 'jersey-core.jar' located in '/opt/GlassFish3/glassfish/modules/jersey-core.jar'.
How can I "override" the internal library 'jersey-core.jar', or give preference to the library 'jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final.jar'?
